# Spring boot - Specify a JRE for the application to run

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, command-prompt

I have a small question. I have a spring boot application which runs perfectly. However, I want to make this application to take a JRE 8 when running the application.

Therefore I am hoping to create a .bat file for this purpose.

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -server -Dspring.config.location=./config/application.properties D:/Work/Software/Java/JDK8/bin/java.exe -jar ./libs/MY_JAR_TO_RUN.jar &
```

I get the following error when I run this command above.

**Could not find or load main class D:.Work.Software.Java.JDK8.bin.java.exe**

This path is the same as I have set in my PATH variable. However this raises the above error.

If I run it without the path like below, the application runs perfectly.

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -server -Dspring.config.location=./config/application.properties -jar ./libs/MY_JAR_TO_RUN.jar &
```

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: what version of `java` is in your `PATH`? run `java -version` to find out

Comment: So you run Java and give a path to another java.exe as argument?? Why don’t you simply use the java.exe at D:/Work/Software/Java/JDK8/bin/?

Comment: My java version is 1.8.0_141. @dpr. I want to move this application to a different environment and most applications in that environment use java 1.7. Changing that is not an option. So I wanna use java 1.8 and I wanna set it in my run script.That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Ran_Macavity `1.8.0_141` *is* java 8... to specify a version different from the one in the `PATH`, follow @dpr advice.

Comment: Try to use this D:/Work/Software/Java/JDK8/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -server -Dspring.config.location=./config/application.properties -jar ./libs/MY_JAR_TO_RUN.jar &